# Transposing a dataframe that contains character strings in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, transpose

I have hundreds of tab-separated tables saved as text files in a folder. I would like to transpose all those tables using R and then export the transposed tables as tab-separated text files. I'm using the following code:

```
files <- list.files()

for (i in files) {
  x <- t(read.table(i, header = TRUE,  sep = "\t"))
  filename <- paste0("transposed_", i)
  write.table(x, file = filename)
}
```

The above code works perfectly well except that, because the tables being transposed contain character strings, the function `t()` returns matrices with all values as strings. As a result, the transposed tables exported with `write.table` have all values within quotation marks `""`.

So, the question is: how could I transpose dataframes that contain character strings without getting all values converted into character strings? If someone can demonstrate this using the following dataset, I can replicate for my task.

```
# Hypothetical dataframe    
data <- data.frame(dist = 1:5,
                   time = 6:10,
                   vel = 11:15,
                   pos = c("x","y","z","w","k"))
row.names(data) <- c("indA","indB","indC","indD","indE")

data
#       dist time vel pos
# indA    1    6  11   x
# indB    2    7  12   y
# indC    3    8  13   z
# indD    4    9  14   w
# indE    5   10  15   k

t(data)
#      indA indB indC indD indE
# dist "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5" 
# time " 6" " 7" " 8" " 9" "10"
# vel  "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
# pos  "x"  "y"  "z"  "w"  "k"

# Even if I use as.data.frame(t(data)), all values remain as character strings
```

I've tried several solutions offered in other topics, but none worked. Also, I'd like (if possible) to perform this task using R base functions only.

Comment: The notion of transposing a `data.frame` while retaining the different (and incompatible) classes is flawed: in a frame, each column is its own vector, and different columns can have different classes, but rows do not have this capability. One cannot, for instance, have a frame where row 1 is integer and row 2 is character. Because of that, the notion of transposing your `data` and keeping the `pos` row as strings and the other rows as integer cannot happen. Having said that, you're writing it to a file, "who cares" what it is when you write? `trimws` them and they'll look normal in the file.

Comment: If the goal is to write without quotes use `write.table(..., quote=FALSE)`

Comment: @r2evans and @Andre Wildberg many thanks! Adding `quote = FALSE` seems easier and worked perfectly.